Is it possible to use an RF button to trigger an event in Bluetooth Web API?
I want to use a wireless button to trigger an event in an "always on" web application.  I think I can make it happen using a bluetooth button (like a camera shutter) with the Bluetooth Web API.
However, I want the button to be always clickable (24/7) and the battery on the bluetooth button will drain too quickly,  Is there a way (or a device) to use an RF button and have the signal received and converted such that it triggers or emulates the Bluetooth event in the web app?
I've tried searching for such a device (RF receiver/Bluetooth transmitter) but have had no luck.
